# How to show all Elements in a Textview

Tags: collections, textview, element, data-class

```
    data class Fruit(val name: String, val price: Int)

    val fruits = arrayOf(Fruit(name = "Apple", price = 2), Fruit(name = "Grape", price = 3), Fruit(name = "Bananna", price = 4))


    for (index in fruits.indices)
        textView.text = fruits[index].name 

    Output = Bananna
```

I cant seem to get all elements of "Name" to reflect in the Textview
Eg.
Apple, Grape, Pear

Comment: You're reassigning `textView.text` in the loop-- did you mean to append to it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but all I want is for all the "name" elements to appear in which ever text view.

Comment: It keeps only showing the last element, yet this does not happen when i dont use a dataclass

Comment: Try `textView.text += fruits[index].name`

Comment: No luck, its not excepting the "+"

Comment: How about `textView.text = textView.text + fruits[index].name`?

Comment: The other option is to "textView.text  = fruits.toString()" but then it prints everything as follows "(Fruit(name = "Apple", price = 2), Fruit(name = "Grape", price = 3), Fruit(name = "Bananna", price = 4))"

Comment: Still no luck with  "textView.text = textView.text + fruits[index].name" Still not excepting the "+"

Comment: OK, you need whatever string append is, which unfortunately I don't know

Comment: OK, final guess `text_view.text = "$text_view.text $fruits[index].name"`

Answer (score 0):

I manage to figure it out !

```
        val fruitNamesonly: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

        for (item in fruits) {
            val token = item.name
            FruitNamesonly.add(token)
        }
```

val fruitNamesonly will be the vaulable you use for what ever